# Fit array of movieclips in a fixed box in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I have this array of movieclips (there can be only one but there can also be like 100) and a big movieclip on the stage with a fixed width and height (it can't be resized).

```
var boxWidth:int = 500
var boxHeight:int = 300
var box:MovieClip = new Movieclip;
box.graphics.beginFill(0x444444);
box.graphics.drawRect(
    0, 
    0, 
    boxWidth, 
    boxHeight
);
box.graphics.endFill(); 
addChild(box);

var movieClipsArray:Array = []; //dynamic number of movieclips

var movieClipsSpacing:int = 10;

for(var i:String in movieClipsArray){
    //calculate x, y, width, and height
    box.addChild(movieClipsArray[i]);
}
```

How can I add all the movieclips from the array to the box, while fullfilling the following requirements?

1. The movieclips may be resized, but they have to keep their height/width ratio
2. The movieclips may not overlap
3. The movieclips may not exceed the borders of the box movieclip
4. There has to be some space between the movieclips (let's say, `10px`)
5. The space of the box movieclip has to be used as efficiently as possible
6. The movieclips don't have to be in the same order, e.g `movieClipsArray[0]` could be at the left top, but also in the right bottom or somewhere in the center

I'm sorry for not having done much myself, but I just don't have any idea where to start

Comment: Are all of the `MovieClips` the same size?

Comment: so if all movieclips can't fit into the box, they can be resized and made smaller?

Comment: @Marcela no, they aren't

Comment: @Andrei-nikolaenko yes, as long as they keep the same height/width ratio (e.g a 600x300 movieclip can be resized to 100x50 but not to 150x150)

Comment: This task has two solutions. One is optimized, which is not easy. And the other is just "workable": Sort all boxes by their size, start from the biggest, if it doesn't fit then squeeze it. Put it in the left top corner. After that you will get up to three containers instead of 1. These are the empty spaces to the right, bottom and bottomright of the placed box. Each becomes a new container. Repeat with the remaining boxes now checking them for best fit against all the new containers, etc. Two containers also can be merged back if they have the same side.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if I'm over complicating this at all, but I'd personally do something like this:

```
var boxWidth:int = 500;
var boxHeight:int = 300;

// each column and row of equally sized movieclip would be 5/7 and 3/7 of the width/height of the box respectively.

mcColumns = ((movieClipsArray.length / 7) * 5); // tells you how many columns
mcRows = ((movieClipsArray.length / 7) * 3); // tells you how many rows

//calculate width
var availableWidth = boxWidth - (mcColumns * 10); //width available after 10px spaces
var mcWidth:int = availableWidth / mcColumns; //width of each box

//calculate height
var availableHeight = boxHeight - (mcRows * 10); //height available after 10px spaces
var mcHeight:int = availableHeight / mcRows; //height of each box

for(var i:int = 0; i<mcColums; i++;){
for(var j:int = 0; i<mcRows; i++;){

//calculate x
movieClipsArray[i+j].width = mcWidth;
movieClipsArray[i+j].x = (availableWidth / mcWidth) * i;
movieClipsArray[i+j].x += 10 * i; //adds the space

//calculate y
movieClipsArray[i+j].height = mcHeight;
movieClipsArray[i+j].y = (availableHeight /mcWidth) * j;
movieClipsArray[i+j].y += 10 * j; //adds the space


box.addChild(movieClipsArray[i+j]);

}
}
```

Please bear in mind that I haven't checked this, I just wrote it to help set you on the right track.

Comment: if they are all equally sized, that would be too easy, I thought they all can be different size (also different width/height ratio)

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko I assumed OP meant to only resize to fit the stage, rather than individual resizing. Hopefully he can clarify and I'll be able to edit my answer if needed.

Comment: @Jonan You could possibly still use similar to the code I submitted, but changing mcWidth and mcHeight to movieClipsArray[i+j].width and movieClipsArray[i+j].height would be closer to what you want. If you need me to rewrite it feel free to ask.